# How do I evaluate this integral of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have a function $f_n:[0,2]->\mathbb R$

$\
 f_n(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   n^3x^2
 &  0<x<1/n\\
   n^3(x-\frac{2}{n})^2       & 1/n\le x<2/n
\\
   0       & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$

I need to calculate $\int_0^2 f(x)dx$ and $\int_0^2f_n(x)dx$.

So $\int_0^2f_n(x)dx=\frac{2}{3}$, but regarding $\int_0^2 f(x)dx$, isnt the integral $\int_0^2 f(x)dx=0?$

If so, why do I get 2 different answers? Im sure $\int_0^2f_n(x)dx=\frac{2}{3}$ is correct.

Comment: Is $f$ the limit of the $f_n$'s? If so, how are you defining convergence? point-wise? Next, if $f_n \to f$, why should you expect $\int_0^2 f_n \to \int_0^2 f$?

Comment: You forgot to define $f$.  If I guess that $f=0$, you are wondering why limits don't pass through integration I guess.  It is because they don't, as this example shows.  But under extra hypotheses they do.  E.g. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: thanks, yes I was defining it as pointwise.

Comment: @Frank: Will you please edit your question to say what $f$ is, and clarify that you are asking why you can't pass limits through integrals?  The question doesn't make sense as written.

Answer (score 1):

From your previous  [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109466/how-to-determine-pointwise-limit-uniform-convergence), I'm assuming you have that $f$  is the pointwise limit of the $f_n$; so, $f$ is identically $0$ on $[0,2]$.

$\int_0^2 f_n(x)\, dx$ is indeed $2/3$ and  $\int_0^2f(x)\, dx$ is indeed $0$.

Everything is ok, though. There is nothing here
 assuring that the integrals $\int_0^2 f_n(x)\,dx$ should converge to $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx $.

In particular, the $f_n$ do not converge uniformly to $f $, as the answer to the aforementioned question shows. 
You are not guaranteed  that $\int_0^2 f_n (x)\,dx \rightarrow \int_0^2 f(x)\,dx$, if you do not have uniform convergence.

I presume the purpose of this exercise is to show that the hypothesis of uniform convergence is *needed* in the following theorem:

If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of Riemann integrable functions over $[a,b]$ and if $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to the function $f$ on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty }\int_a^b f_n(x)\,dx=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks for your insight!