# pointwise convergence of a piecewise function with intervals dependent on n

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

so I have a function $f_n:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ defined as                      $$ f_n(x) = $$\begin{cases}
   \tfrac{2n}{n-1}x
 &  0\le x\le\tfrac{n-1}{2n}\\
   2-\tfrac{2n}{n-1}x       & \tfrac{n-1}{2n}\le x \le\tfrac{n-1}{n}
\\
   0       & \tfrac{n-1}{n}\le x \le\ 1
  \end{cases}
and I'm trying to figure out the pointwise limit.
my reasoning so far is 
 if $ x=0 $,$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(0)=0$ for all n.

the next part is the part im having a little trouble understanding, and any clarification would be much appreciated.

can i pretty much ignore the middle term by saying if $x>0$, then let $x>\tfrac{N-1}{N}$ , then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n>N$. so the pointwise limit of $f(x)$ is $0$.

If this is correct (which i feel it is based on examples i've seen) is the reason this is so because the intervals involving n become arbitrarily small as n gets very large and so we can essentially ignore them ?

Comment: It's unfortunately not correct - try sketching the graph for some $n$, and notice it's piecewise linear.

Comment: well, this question changed a lot

Comment: sorry, I had a mistake because I copied and pasted a math text command is it correct now ?

Comment: now it no longer converges pointwise to 0. It's also a completely different sequence

Comment: what is it about my reasoning that's incorrect ?

Comment: I was basically using this question as a template to solve mine https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109466/how-to-determine-pointwise-limit-uniform-convergence?rq=1 , I don't why that function converges to zero but mine does not, it seems like pretty much the same question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

For $x\in (0,\frac {1}{2}) $,

using the fact that for great enough $n $, we have

$$0 <x <\frac {1}{2}-\frac {1}{2n}<\frac {1}{2} $$
thus for large enough $n $,

$$f_n (x)=\frac {2nx}{n-1} $$ and $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n (x)=2x .$$

For $ \frac {1}{2} \le x <1$ and great $n $,

$$\frac {n-1}{2n}\le x\le 1-\frac {1}{n} $$
thus $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n (x)=2-2x $$

finally, for $x=1 \;, f_n (1)=0$.

Comment: haha salahamam I was just about to ask you would this be the answer and then you edited your post and answered before I finished typing, spooky oO XD. Thanks so much! your answer perfectly cleared up my confusions. Just to clarify though our sequence of functions converges pointwise to a piecewise function with $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$ , $f(x)=2x$ for $0<x<\tfrac{1}{2}$ , $f(x)=2-2x$ for $\tfrac{1}{2} \le x<1$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x=1$ ?

Comment: @exodius Your sequence is very intresting (+1).